# Make my flipping div responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, flip

I have created one app using [Quick Flip 2](http://jonraasch.com/blog/quickflip-2-jquery-plugin).

Here is my Code :

```
<div class="quickFlip">
    <div id="imgContainer" class="blackPanel">               
        <center>
            <input id="click_flip" type="button" class="quickFlipCta" value="Flip to see the Answer" >
        </center>
    </div>

    <div id="b" class="redPanel">
        <!-- <h4>A plugin for jQuery</h4>
        <p><em>By Jon Raasch</em></p> -->
        <center>
            <input id="flip_again" class="first quickFlipCta" type="button" value="Flip Again" >
        </center>
        <center>
            <input id="shownext" type="button" value="Show Next" >
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want my div with class `quickFlip` to become responsive.

Here is my Css

```
body {
    min-width: 1280px;
}

.quickFlip, .quickFlip3 {
    height: 480px;
    width: 800px;
}

.quickFlip2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

/* the rest of this is irrelevent */

H1, H2 {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 15px;
    line-height: 32px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
    magin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.redPanel, .blackPanel {
    text-align: center;
}

.half-col {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

/**** panels ****/

.quickFlip, .quickFlip2, .quickFlip3 {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Sans-serif, sans;
    font-size: 13px;
    position: relative;
}

.quickFlip .blackPanel, .quickFlip2 .blackPanel, .quickFlip3 .blackPanel {
    background-color: #FFD993;
    color: darkbrown;
    border: 1px outset #A61C14;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
}

.quickFlip .redPanel, .quickFlip2 .redPanel, .quickFlip3 .redPanel {
    background-color: #75941f;
    color: #FFF;
    border: 1px outset #4f6417;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
}

.half-col p {
    padding: 5px;
    margin:0 30px 10px 30px;
}

.half-col p.panel-content {
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.half-col h3, .half-col h4 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 35px;
}

.half-col h3 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size:24px;
    line-height:24px;
}

.half-col .redPanel h3 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.half-col .first {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.half-col EM {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
}

.half-col A.quickFlipCta {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 65px;
    width: 210px;
    font-size: 15px;
    outline: none;
}

.quickFlip2 .redPanel a {
    color: #FFF;
}

.quickFlipCta {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here is my JS code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.quickFlip').quickFlip();

    $('.quickFlip3').quickFlip({
        vertical : true
    });

    $('.quickFlip2').quickFlip();
});
</script>
```

What Changes should i do

Comment: Any reason to not actually flip? http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/

Comment: I have created this app to show few number of objects on one side and on flipping to the other side it will show me the answer. This is the reason of using `quick flip 2` template

Comment: If you wanna do responsive stuff, start coding with standard HTML.

Answer (score 0):

add 100% width in ".quickFlip" and remove min-width from body .

```
.quickFlip{
    height: 480px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: no its not working. When i am resizing my browsers width my div is not adjusting.

Comment: have u removed min-width from body??

Comment: yes @abhineet i want my div like this only but in my case it is not working with picture. I have pasted your full CSS code in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your js code?
Did you add:

```
$(function() {
    $('.quickFlip').quickFlip();
});
```

or is it totally missing?

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hhrr9/

working on it